# Improving efficiency of QuerySet filter by most recent record of a certain "type" (attribute)

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-2.2

I'll try and keep this as condensed as possible. I have the following query:

```
organisation_survey_results = OrganisationSurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user=user
).order_by('survey', 'created_date')
```

This also produces a similar result:

```
organisation_survey_results = OrganisationSurveyResult.objects.filter(
    user=user
).order_by(
    'survey__id',
    '-created_date',
).distinct('survey__id',)
```

In the above, I filter according to the user match. All is good. I have returned the 5 records for that user.

Now, as mentioned, each record comes with the following `attributes` and `attribute` "(chains?)":

Unique `slug` attribute:

```
organisation_survey_result.organisation_survey.survey.slug
```

Immutable (non-changing, write once on creation) `created_date` attribute:

```
organisation_survey_result.created_date
```

For the five records, if I loop over them, I have:

```
django_1    | food
django_1    | 2019-08-12 15:45:49.384071+00:00
django_1    | drink
django_1    | 2019-08-12 15:45:49.390939+00:00
django_1    | politics
django_1    | 2019-08-12 15:45:49.397714+00:00
django_1    | money
django_1    | 2019-08-12 15:45:49.406612+00:00
django_1    | food
django_1    | 2019-08-13 11:26:55.831903+00:00
```

As you can see, I have two records where the attribute `organisation_survey.survey.slug` with `food` appears twice. **For a given user, this is fine.** *Records can, and will, supersede each over other time.*

---

My question:

Is there a way whereby I can filter these records out on the Query? (for performance efficiencies)... I'd like to be able to perform this on the `QuerySet` level to perform a less stressful `serialization` of the data.

---

Versions:

```
`Django==2.2.1`
`djangorestframework==3.9.3`
```

Database Engine:

```
`PostgreSQL`
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for me, although not in one QuerySet, the output was a QuerySet which should be "serializable":

Give our QuerySets a head start by filtering by the current user:

```
organisation_survey_results = OrganisationSurveyResult.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Get the `latest_records` for each "organisation_survey" type.

```
latest_records = organisation_survey_results.values(
    'user', 'organisation_survey'
).annotate(
    latest_created_date=Max('created_date')
)
```

Going back to the initial QuerySet, filter by the `created_date` being "in" (`created_date__in`) the `latest_records` taken from the `latest_created_date` record.

```
organisation_survey_results = organisation_survey_results.filter(
    created_date__in=latest_records.values('latest_created_date')
).order_by(
    '-created_date'
)
```

Gives me exactly what I describe I needed in the above solution.